# How do I place a custom marker in a google-maps activity from an object information

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to place a marker on a specific location. At first, I thought this would be simple to do but somehow I'm getting confused and I haven't found something that actually gives me what I need. I've tried to base my activity on whats it's done in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HD48FBwY9U0

My activity starts by receiving an object information on a getIntent() which I then extract the information. In that object (in this case, a car), there is a lot of properties and 2 of them, are the latitude and longitude. The previous are in Double values.

The problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to input the information that I got from the object into the program. I'm placing the code below. Any suggestions?

```
public class Geolocalizcao extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
public static int REQUEST_ERROR_CODE;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geolocalizcao);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    Intent i = getIntent();
    CarDataset cardata = (CarDataset) i.getExtras().getParcelable("select");

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        return;
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Here!");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(3));

    if(client != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


}

public boolean checkLocationPermission()
{
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
// When connection is lost...
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Lost connection. Trying to reconnect...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    client.connect();
}

@Override
// Called when the API client doesnt sucessufly connect
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{

    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution())
    {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, connectionResult.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_ERROR_CODE );
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
    {
        Log.e("LOG", "Exception:", e);
    }
}
```

Here's the class CarDataset that I use:

```
public class CarDataset implements Parcelable
{

int vehicleID;
String model;
String licencePlate;
String brand;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;

public CarDataset(Integer nVehicleID, String nModel, String nLicencePlate, String nBrand, Double nLatitude, Double nLongitude)
{
    this.vehicleID = nVehicleID;
    this.model = nModel;
    this.licencePlate = nLicencePlate;
    this.brand = nBrand;
    this.latitude = nLatitude;
    this.longitude = nLongitude;
}

public int getVehicleID() {
    return vehicleID;
}

public void setVehicleID(int vehicleID) {
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getLicencePlate() {
    return licencePlate;
}

public void setLicencePlate(String licencePlate) {
    this.licencePlate = licencePlate;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    dest.writeInt(vehicleID);
    dest.writeString(model);
    dest.writeString(licencePlate);
    dest.writeString(brand);
    dest.writeDouble(latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(longitude);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<CarDataset> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<CarDataset>()
{
    public CarDataset createFromParcel(Parcel input)
    {
        return new CarDataset(input);
    }

    public CarDataset[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new CarDataset[size];
    }
};

private CarDataset(Parcel input)
{
    vehicleID = input.readInt();
    model = input.readString();
    licencePlate = input.readString();
    brand = input.readString();
    latitude = input.readDouble();
    longitude = input.readDouble();
}
```

}

Comment: Show your CarDataset class

Comment: @DanielNugent done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a LatLng object with the latitude and longitude from the CarDataset object that you get from the Intent.

```
Marker carMarker;
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (cardata != null) {
        LatLng latLngCar = new LatLng(cardata.latitude, cardata.longitude);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLngCar);
        markerOptions.title("Car");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());

        carMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }


    //.............

}
```

You will also need to modify `onCreate()` so that `cardata` is an instance variable:

```
CarDataset cardata;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geolocalizcao);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

    Intent i = getIntent();

    //use instance variable:
    cardata = (CarDataset) i.getExtras().getParcelable("select");

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Comment: Worked! You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(3));

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.title("Here!")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker())
.position(latlng_object));
```

Comment: @Manuel please replace your MarkerOptions with my solution

Comment: I assume that latlng_object is the place where a LatLng containing my values are to be placed. But how do I send that information that is currently on "onCreate", in the beginning section of the code? @yash786

Comment: @ManuelCruz No need to send the information on "onCreate".